# Using PHP to change image brightness

Tags: php, image-processing

I have written code for a client to upload images to their website. They have now asked if it is possible to add a facility to change the brightness of the images once they are uploaded (permanent change to the images). I did explain that it's probably easier to change this before uploading but decided to investigate anyway, so my question is:
Is there anyway of changing image brightness permanently using php?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`imagefilter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php) for this task:

```
$bool = imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS, 10); // arg3 can be -255 to +255
```